# Proof verification: Uniformly continuous maps preserve total boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Just want to know if my proof is right and if there are other easier methods to go about it.

> If $f: (M,d)\to (N,d')$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ maps totally bounded sets to totally bounded sets.

Suppose $A$ is totally bounded in $M$. By definition/characterisation we know that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist finitely many sets $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ such that $\text{diam} A_i < \epsilon$ for all $i$ and $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$.
We want to show that $f(A)$ is totally bounded. Choose arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$d(a,b) < \delta \implies d'(f(a),f(b)) < \epsilon$$ for every $a,b\in M$.
For this $\delta$, we can find sets $A_1,...,A_n$ such that $\text{diam} A_i < \delta$ for all $i$ and $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. This follows from total-boundedness of $A$.
$$\text{diam} A_i = \sup_{a,b \in A_i} \{d(a,b)\} < \delta \implies d(a,b) < \delta$$ for all $a,b\in A_i$ for every $i$. But, $d(a,b) < \delta \implies d'(f(a),f(b)) < \epsilon$. So, $\text{diam} f(A_i) \le \epsilon$ for every $i$. Also,
$$A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \implies f(A) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n f(A_i) $$
and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $f(A)$ is totally bounded. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me, except I would do the following to make it neater:

> Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$d(a,b) < \delta \implies d'(f(a),f(b)) < \epsilon/2$$ for every $a,b\in M$.

Then, you would obtain $\text{diam}\ f(A_i) \le \epsilon/2$ for every $1\le i\le n$, which would mean $\text{diam}\ f(A_i) < \epsilon$ for every $1\le i\le n$.